# Trying to copy flange file to $FOAM_RUN in open foam

Tags: copy, openfoam

I am trying "cp -r flange/ $FOAM_RUN/ "in openfoan10 ubuntu terminal [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZS3E.jpg) but its showing can not create directory so please help to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the destination directory `$FOAM_RUN` does not exist. You need to create it first:

```
mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN
```

Then, you can try your command:

```
cp -r flange/ $FOAM_RUN/
```